# Durandal: one compositionComplete to rule them all

Tags: javascript, durandal, lifecycle

With Durandal we have the compositionComplete event for last minutes processing on the view.
Currently my view composition hierarchy is quite complex, and I need to do various UI processing at different point in the app.

To avoid calling multiple times the same UI related code, and to guarantee it will be called at least once when some view needs it, I need a finalCompositionComplete() hook somewhere.

I didn't find such an event in the current Durandal implementation so I was thinking of adding it to the `composition.js` file (I figured out the `endComposition()` function would be a good place to start...)

It's obviously a bad idea modifying original durandal files for maintenance reasons.

**Is there a better solution?** One that is more maintenance friendly..

What I've done so far (and seems to be working):

- created a `lifecycle` plugin in the plugins directory of durandal (and injected it in the composition module)
- modified the `composition.js` file's `endComposition()` function
- Now I can register callbacks through my lifecycle plugin and it will be called once at the very end

---

**The endComposition() function in the composition.js file:**

```
function endComposition() {
    compositionCount--;

    if (compositionCount === 0) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var i = compositionCompleteCallbacks.length;

            while(i--) {
                try{
                    compositionCompleteCallbacks[i]();
                }catch(e){
                    system.error(e);
                }
            }

            // my modification is right here:
            lifecycle.finalCompositionComplete();
            compositionCompleteCallbacks = [];
        }, 1);
    }
}
```

**lifecycle plugin**

```
define(['durandal/system', 'underscore'], function (system, _) {

        var _nameCounter = 0;
        var _processes = {};

        return {
            registerFinalProcess: register,
            finalCompositionComplete: processFinal
        };

        function register(processName, callback) {
            processName = processName || '_noname' + _nameCounter++;
            _processes[processName] = callback;
        }

        function processFinal() {
            _.each(_.pairs(_processes), function(pair) {
                try {
                    if (typeof pair[1] === 'function') {
                        pair[1]();
                    }
                    delete _processes[pair[0]];
                } catch(e) {
                    system.log('error:could not call ' + pair[0]);
                }
            });

            _processes = {};
            _nameCounter = 0;
        }

    });
```

**Anywhere, anytime in my app:**

```
lifecycle.registerFinalProcess('someCallbackId', someFunction);
```

Comment: This seems as a good solution. Maybe add a single setImmediate or setTimeout so you can be sure the browser has rendered everything, instead of doing this in all the handlers.

Comment: What seems to be the problem, because Durandal already does what you're doing (see http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html)?.  Also, we have found this kind of compositional dependency to be a problem as the application grows.  We use postal.js as a client-side message bus, and route messages at the appropriate times in the composition to hook the lifecycle.  You could also use Durandal's built-in pub/sub.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I know about durandal's hooks in the lifecycle. There's no problem with it. But what I want is to know when the last (and only the last) compositionComplete has been fired, after a user action or after initial load. Pub/sub and other messaging are of no use here, because you'd need someone to initiate the message/event/whatever.. (and if Durandal don't do it, you still have to modify the composition.js file in this case)

Comment: You could structure your views so that you have a "root" view which is essentially empty, but on that view's viewModel, you run the "finalCompositionComplete" code there. That way its at the top of the "view stack" and will run last.